# How to rerun my program when an error occurs [Vb6]

Tags: vb6, error-handling

How to rerun my program when an error occurs [Vb6] ?

Comment: You need to provide more explanation of your problem and your requirement - otherwise I have to agree with the votes to close

Comment: What are you trying to do and what error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

In VB6 you have the option of starting a program by launching a form or by calling some global "Main" routine (in project settings).  Select that latter option (global Main routine).

In your global main routine, make it something like this:

```
Public Sub MyMain()
    On Error Goto errHandler
    frmMain.Show
    Exit Sub
errHandler:
    Unload frmMain
    Resume
End Sub
```

The `Resume` will restart at the same line that caused the error, and since there's really only one line, it will always load the same form.

This assumes that you have a main form called `frmMain` and that it can get through the `Form_Load` subroutine successfully.

Comment: `frmMain.Show` does not block so the form is shown and control returns immediately and the function exit is executed

Comment: Do you mean that http://hotfile.com/dl/92626697/494ff2f/Error.rar.html ? But it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Resume Next to continue processing the next instructions

```
Public Sub MyMain()
    On Error Resume Next
    aNumber = someNumber / 0    'Divide by Zero will yield a run time error
    If Err<>0 Then         'In case you want to re-act with the error to the user
        MsgBox "Divide by Zero Occurred"
    End If
    On Error Goto 0    'This will un-do the effect of On Error Resume Next, meaning
                       ' that if any other error occurs, there will be a runtime error
                       ' use this if you intentionally want to
End Sub
```